# getInitialLink is not working but onLink is working in react-native-firebase v6

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links, react-native-firebase

I am using the following code in App.js - componentDidMount

```
    firebase
      .dynamicLinks()
      .getInitialLink()
      .then(link => {
        if (link) {
          if (link.url.includes('/s/')) {
            this.handleSignupURL(link.url)
          }
        }
      })


    firebase.dynamicLinks().onLink(({ url }) => {
      if (url && url.includes('/s/')) {
        this.handleSignupURL(url)
      }
    })
  }
```

On clicking the dynamic link: When the app is active, onLink handler is fired and the app handles it correctly. But when the app is closed, getInitialLink returns a null. Any solution to get the initial link?

I am using react-native-firebase v6, react-native corresponding to expo 36. The installation is performed as per the new react-native-firebase [quick start](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/dynamic-links/quick-start). I am using the iOS app.

Answer (score 4):

I am running into this issue on iOS now as well. I am not sure if this is a good workaround as I have not yet shipped to production but one way I've got things to work on iOS when the app is not in background is use the Linking package from RN like so in my splash screen:

```
        Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
            if (url){
                Linking.openURL(url).then((response) => {
                    Actions.reset('MainFeed');
                });

            } else {
                console.log('no url');
                Actions.reset('MainFeed');
            }
        });
```

Then on my componentDidMount on my MainFeed screen, I set up a listener for onLink. Since we are now calling openURL while the app is open, the onLink from firebase triggers and i am able to parse the deep link and route the user where they need to go.

I have not tested if this method will allow links to persists app store installation

**EDIT:** I have tested this and it works all the way through. The link persists through download thru app store/google play